# Laravel Route Generation

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have route defined in routes.php file as following:

```
Route::get('/configuration/{id}', 'ConfigController@getConfigDetailsById');
```

I am trying to generate url to that route in my blade template in the  tags, based on the selection.

```
$url = '{{route('configuration', 1)}}';
```

but I am getting an error, that Route [configuration] not defined.

Also, how can use a variable inside this route generation. The following fails with an error that variable id is not defined, although it is defined and initialised.

```
$url = '{{route('configuration', $id)}}';
```

Comment: I really, really encourage you to re-skim the documentation. There are a number of really basic mistakes you've made here that the documentation would help you avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [give your route a name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes) to use it like that.

```
Route::get('/configuration/{id}', 'ConfigController@getConfigDetailsById')
    ->name('configuration);
```

As for `$id`, be wary of variable scope. It may be defined in the *controller*, but that doesn't mean it exists in the *view*. You'll need to [pass it to the view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data), something like:

```
return view('configuration', ['id' => $id]);
```

As for using `$id` in the `route()` call, per the docs, [you need to pass an array of data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route):

```
$url = '{{route('configuration', ['id' => 1])}}';
```

and as for *that* bit, you can't use Blade instructions in PHP code like that, so it'll be something more like:

```
$url = route('configuration', ['id' => 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can route fine now. But '$url = route('configuration', ['id' => 1]);' I need to route dynamically based on user selection, so hardcoding this value would not work. Any suggestion, on how the dynamic routing should be done in Laravel/Blade template? What I want to do is if user select itemid=1, I want to display all the configurations of that item so url should be like "http://localhost:80/configuration/1" and if the user selects item#2, the url to be loaded should be "http://localhost:80/configuration/2". Any idea how to implement this? Thanks!

Comment: Don't overthink it. `$url = route('configuration', ['id' => $id]);`

Comment: Thanks again. I think I know why that $id var is causing an issue. This code is part a of js function - which gets called when the selection changes for a dropdown element. The is $id variable is defined in that function to that contains the current selected itemId (is client side variable) and the function `route('configuration', ['id' => $id]);` is executed on server side by PHP. So this $id variable is not available at this time, causing an error. As I just copied the following to the javascript function and it's still an error. `$url = route('configuration', ['id' => $id]);`

Comment: You can't just copy PHP into a JS function without some work. I'm not sure I can help you further without a lot more of your code being shown.